# Magento 2 Layered Navigation SEO Friendly Urls

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, seo

Context:

When selecting a filter on a category page, that displays multiple products, a url is built.

For example. Selecting color => red will result in the following url: 
www.shopurl.com/[category]/[subcategory]...?color=152.

The number being the id. I wish to keep all functionality but display the label. e.g. url..?color=red

I'm not expecting a full "tutorial" on how to this. But I would need some pointers and maybe some answers?

1. I suspect that at some point the argument from the url is read and the product collection is filtered. Where does this happen?
2. When a filter is clicked the page refreshes with the new url that contains the filter. Where does this happen?

Many thanks.

Comment: Check this out https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208230/magento-2-where-code-are-the-filters-from-the-layered-navigation-applied-to-th

Comment: do find any answer?

Comment: @SagarParikhSGR see above comment with q/a